# How can I customize the DDL generated with Hibernate's hbm2ddl (using annotations)?

Tags: java, hibernate, ddl

Here's what I want to do:
I'm using Hibernate (3.3.2) to map my Ingres 10 database. My java entities are generated after a meta model, so we decided to use annotations to ease things.
What we want to do after the code generation is generate the DDL instructions to create the database so we use the hbm2ddl tool and we have something like:

```
drop table xxx;
create table xxx ...;
```

What I miss here are extra SQL statement to e.g. add privileges on tables, something like:

```
drop table xxx;
create table xxx ...;
grant xxx on table xxx;
```

I know I could use something called database-object to generate such statements but I think it's only available with the XML mapping. Can you confirm this?
If that is confirmed, do you see a better solution for doing such a thing?
Many thanks to all.

Comment: Are you using the hbm2ddl to effectively create your database objects, or just to generate the statements?

Comment: I wish I could use hbm2ddl just to generate the 'extra' statements. My entities already exist and they are annotated, so hbm2ddl is able to generate the statements like 'create table xxx'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Hibernate (only NHibernate) that much and I don't know these annotations stuff very well. But I'm pretty sure that this is only available in XML mapping files.

You may find a way to combine annotations and XML mappings. If this is not possible, consider to switch to XML entirely, it is generally more powerful and you get more control.

Comment: Well, I thought of it (to use only XML) but at the time of writing, the project is too much advanced to switch. I still think Hibernate is lacking some functionnalities through its annotation system. Too bad for me.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, and not the prettiest solution, but here's a quick and dirty bash script to run in conjunction with maven.  Hopefully it helps someone else grappling with this issue.

```
#!/bin/bash

SQL_FILE=$1
GROUP=$2
COMPILED=$1.tmp
SCHEMA_DROP=$3
if [ "$3" == "" ]; then
    SCHEMA_DROP="true"
fi


mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl -Dschema.file=$SQL_FILE -Dschema.drop=$SCHEMA_DROP

if [ "$SQL_FILE" == "" ] || [ "$GROUP" == "" ] ; then
    echo "Usage: $0 {SQL_FILE} {GROUP} [DROP_SCHEMA]"
    echo "Where: "
    echo "SQL_FILE: path to sql file relative to the root of the project"
    echo "GROUP: the predefined database group on which to grant access"
    echo "DROP_SCHEMA: true|false per the hbm2ddl 'drop' parameter.  Defaults to true"
    echo "NOTE: In order for this to work properly, the pom configuration of the hibernatetool should be parameterized.  For example:"
    echo '<hbm2ddl outputfilename="../../../${schema.file}" format="true" drop="${schema.drop}" />'
    exit;
fi

echo "" > $COMPILED
GRANT=""
while read line
do
    echo $line >> $COMPILED
    if [[ $line =~ .*create.table.([A-Za-z_-]*) ]]; then
        GRANT="$GRANT\ngrant all on table ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} to group $GROUP;" >> $COMPILED 
    fi
done < $SQL_FILE

echo -e $GRANT >> $COMPILED

mv $COMPILED $SQL_FILE
```

I like to put my schema file into a src directory for check-in, such as src/main/db/myschema.sql, hence the dir up values in the outputfilename attribute (see the NOTE in the usage comments).  To run this script with file name "genSchema.sh" from the root of the project in cygwin:

```
./genSchema.sh src/main/db/myschema.sql mygroup
```

The regexp and generated grant lines are for the postgresql dialect.  They'd probably need a slight modification for other dialects.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I wish I could find a way to customize the ddl statement without the need of an external shell. Actually, I want to launch my build command on maven (let's say mvn install) and with the call to hbm2ddl as a plugin during the a specific phase. That let me find the ddl script in the target/hibernate3/sql directory. So I use another maven plugin (after the execution of the hibernate one) that is called maven-replacer-plugin and which performs the same string replacement as your script but INSIDE the maven build process which suits better my need.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks very much for sharing that plugin. I too would rather the solution be integrated with the mvn build.  I'm glad to see someone took the time to create it and will check it out.